# Setting itemindent in enumerate environment

Tags: enumerate

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

I want to make this numbered list : 

\begin{enumerate}
[leftmargin=*, labelindent=15pt, labelsep=1.0em, font=\normalfont, label=\arabic*)]
  \item \lipsum[1]
  \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

Look like this : 

1)\quad \lipsum[1]

2)\quad \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\itemindent` is wrong in your descriptive text at the end of your post. Use `\verb!\itemindent!

Comment: `\itemintent` is a command that expects a length value as input -- your usage of it in `...setting \itemindent` is just wrong

Comment: Oh my: Just remove the reference of `\itemindent` in your code -- your example isn't compilable at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `wide` option as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
[labelsep=1.0em, font=\normalfont, label=\arabic*), wide=\parindent]
  \item \lipsum[1]
  \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

> With this convenience key, the leftmargin is null and the label is part of the text—in other word, the items look like ordinary paragraphs.[...]

See section '3.9 “Wide” lists'  of the `enumitem` documentation for more details.

To indent the first line of the items equally to the indentation of paragraphs, you can use `wide=\parindent` or just `wide`.

Comment: The labels aren't indented far enough when I do this.

Comment: @RandyRanderson: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Okay. I came up with the same thing after looking at the documentation you referenced. Thanks.

Comment: @Leandriis: ‘`items look like ordinary paragraphs`’ is not exactly true with your code, since you added `leftmargin=*`: there will be a (list) left margin.

Comment: @Bernard: You are right. Thanks for pointing this out. I have must have been overlooking the additional margin and have now edited my answer accordingly.